# How can I do clipboard-like operations without using the real clipboard?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, clipboard

I am looking to write a program (in Delphi or C++) to protect my passwords, and I would like to be able to copy and paste them. Is it possible to copy and paste, *per se*, without the data going to the clipboard, sort of my own custom clipboard?

I want to be able pull the password from an encrypted database and post it to my bank website, email, online games, etc., without using the clipboard as an extra precaution against keyloggers and the like.

Comment: Surely there are ready-made tools that do this? Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Try these different Data Exchange options. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632538(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Nocturnal: DDE won't help him much.   Remember that if you only wrote one side of an application, you have to use something that is already supported by the other side.  The clipboard works with any text-entry control already in windows, but not much else does, thus the sticky nature of JamesW's problem.

Comment: @Warren P: But DDE isn't the only option, you also got Data Copy. All I did was provide a listing hoping them to be helpful. ;)

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes there may well be solutions similar to what I want out there. However I want A.) the joy of doing such a thing myself and B.) to know that I have written the application and know that it is 100% safe.

Comment: @JamesW Security is hard. Unless you are a trained security professional then doing it yourself will probably guarantee that it won't be safe. I honestly don't mean that in a derogatory way. If I were to try and do it myself I'd fully expect to fail!

Comment: @David Heffernan: No offense, fully understand. I think I was assuming that a keylogger would only record keystrokes and copy the contents of clipboard. I was only hoping to circumvent this by pulling the passwords from an encrypted database and passing them to other applications. I never thought about the keylogger intercepting the windows messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject keyboard keystrokes into other applications without using the clipboard.  But then you would not be using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> as your hotkey.

Maybe you want another global hotkey (yes you can do that) that will find  the currently focused window, and send keystrokes to it. You can do that.

For [reference.](http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/windows/simulate_the_pressing_of_keyboard_keys.html)

Comment: This seems to be along the lines of what I would like to do. Basically I want to be able pull the password from an encrypted database and post it to my bank website, email, online games etc, without using the clipboard as an extra precaution against keyloggers and the like

Comment: I believe that the bank website people will be actively working to block you.

Comment: Keyloggers will see the window messages that you will be sending. So actually, you won't help that problem one bit. :-)

Comment: Accepting Warrens info, I was assuming that a custom made app would circumvent the possibility of a keylogger if there was no typing or clipboard copy and paste happening. Thanks Warren

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the clipboard for this at all. Unless the user wants to put data onto the clipboard, you should NOT put data onto the clipboard. The clipboard is a shared resource, intended for the convenience of the user, not the programmer.

Comment: Chris, the question was how *NOT* to use the clipboard; in fact, the phrase "without...the clipboard" was actually used twice in the question. Read a little more carefully, maybe?

Comment: To the downvoters - Yes I did read the question, but I knew that the solutions would inevitably include ideas that DO use the clipboard, such as the one by O.D. and I want to discourage that sort of solution.  So if you're going to ding me, fine, but at least downvote those answers too!

Comment: Chris this is exactly my concern, I do not want to use the clipboard in any fashion. Though it seems that most solutions to my problem lead back to the unsecure clipboard